# A component that prevents the usual existence check or None, but how to avoid this repetition?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Many times in my components/pages I need to use this pattern:

```html
{#if player.name}
  {player.name}
{:else}
  None
{/if}
```

So I created a new component called `MaybeNone`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let condition = false;
</script>

{#if !condition}
    None
{:else}
    <slot />
{/if}
```

to use like this:

```html
<MaybeNone condition={!!player.name}>
  Name is: {player.name}
</MaybeNone>
```

but sometimes I need to use methods like:

```html
{#if player.name}
  {calculate_player_name(player)}
{:else}
  None
{/if}
```

with:

```
export const calculate_player_name = (
    player: Pick<Player, 'name' | 'nickname'>
): string => {
    // calculate result...

    return result;
};

player?: {
    name?: string | null;
    nickname?: string | null;
    team?: string | null;
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
  } | null;
}>;
```

And now the usage of the `MaybeNone` component is not good:

```html
<MaybeNone condition={!!player.name}>
  <!-- There is an error here because I need to check player.name before calling `calculate_player_name()` obviously -->
  {calculate_player_name(player)}
</MaybeNone>
```

and I'm forced to use instead:

```html
<MaybeNone condition={!!player.name}>
  {#if player.name}
    {calculate_player_name(player)}
  {/if}
</MaybeNone>
```

because the Typescript error is of course:

```bash
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Player, "name" | "nickname">'.ts(2345)
```

which makes the usage of `MaybeNone` useless or not so good as I thought.

Can you suggest an alternative? A fix?

Thanks for your amazing help!

Comment: Are you compiling to custom elements? This should *not* be an issue otherwise. [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/d84ad594f2804091a48401414ed99da0?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Thank you. I'm talking about typescript errors of course.

Comment: Your code works but this is not formally correct in typescript.

Comment: I updated the question with the tyepscript error. Sorry.

Comment: What is the type of the `player` variable? Using strict typing, I already get an error on `condition` in most cases if `name` is not known to exist.

Comment: Sorry. player can be {...}, null or undefined.

Comment: Then how are the properties defined, would the condition on just `player` be enough?

Comment: I updated question with player type extrapolated from other generated types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would approach this via a generic component that has [slot properties](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot-slot-key-value), something like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  type T = $$Generic;
  export let maybe: T | null | undefined;

  // Workaround for type not being narrowed correctly in parent
  $: notNull = maybe as T; 
</script>

{#if maybe}
  <slot value={notNull} />
{:else}
  None
{/if}
```

Which then can be used along the lines of:

```html
<MaybeNone maybe={player} let:value>
  {calculate_player_name(value)}
</MaybeNone>
```

This should work according to the types of the function, but they probably are inaccurate if you need to check that `name` is defined as well. Making sure that this is the case would be a bit more verbose:

```html
<MaybeNone maybe={player?.name == null ? null : player} let:value>
  {calculate_player_name(value)}
</MaybeNone>
```

(If `player` itself can be `undefined`/`null`, there really should be a `?.` on property access. TS's strict null checks will cause errors otherwise.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Is there a way to avoid the `null ? null : player` thing?

Comment: And second question: where does `$$Generic` come from?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to avoid that. For generics syntax see [this RFC](https://github.com/dummdidumm/rfcs/blob/ts-typedefs-within-svelte-components/text/ts-typing-props-slots-events.md).