# Why this object is possibly null or undefined if it's in an else if?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm using the below code in a component:

- Box.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    type T = $$Generic;

    export let loading = false;
    export let error = false;
    export let value: T | null | undefined = undefined;
</script>

<div>
    {#if loading}
        Loading...
    {:else if error}
        Error...
    {:else if value}
    <slot {value} />
    {/if}
</div>
```

Using it like this:

```html
<Box
    loading={$player_service.loading}
    error={$player_service.error}
    value={$player_service.data?.player}
    let:value={player}
>
  <!-- Here player is still possibly `null` or `undefined`, why? -->

  {player.lastname}
</Box>
```

I expect `player` to be **not null** and **not undefined** because of the `{:else if value}` in `Box.svelte`.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely just a bug, already reported [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1832).

I provided a workaround in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117597/a-component-that-prevents-the-usual-existence-check-or-none-but-how-to-avoid-th).